# IIS Manager for Remote Administration 1.2 Won't Install

Tags: iis-7

I have Windows 7 Professional on a 64bit computer. I want to install IIS Manager for Remote Administration 1.2 to manage IIS on a Windows Server 2012R2 computer.

I downloaded: inetmgr_x86_en-US.msi from the Microsoft website. It was the only file for x86. When I try to install the application I get the following error message:

> The 32-bit version of Internet Information Services (IIS) 7+ Manager
>   cannot be installed on a 64-bit edition of Microsoft Windows.

I currently have IIS Manager 6.1 installed. I can't find a separate 64-bit version of IIS 7+ Manager.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get IIS 7+ manager installed?

Answer (score 1):

Use `inetmgr_amd64_en-US.msi`. amd64 means exactly the same as x64, per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64.

Download from the same location as the x32 version, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41177.

The following blog post contains some useful info on configuring your server and workstation to permit access, http://woshub.com/remote-iis-management-in-windows-server-2012/.